# Can you remind me again?

Tags: phrase-request

In English one often says things like

> What was that movie you were telling me about again?

or

> Could you tell me your name again?

The word "again" is a polite courtesy to tell the listener that you're aware that they've already answered your question, but that you've forgotten the answer.

Is there a general format for these kinds of questions in German?

Comment: While "nochmal" sounds good, I would probably say "Wie war Ihr Name auch wieder?"

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I’ve lived both in Northern and Southern Germany, and I don’t think I’ve ever heard “auch wieder” being used in that context.

Comment: @Philipp: But I have, and not just once.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I didn't want to sound condescending. I'm just surprised about this sentence, and Google doesn't yield any hits for it except this thread: https://www.google.de/search?source=hp&ei=zKYPW9fCNNLnsAHzmJmYCg&q=%22Wie+war+ihr+Name+auch+wieder%22&oq=%22Wie+war+ihr+Name+auch+wieder%22&gs_l=mobile-gws-wiz-hp.12...7081.20892..27137...0....133.1726.16j4......0....1.......0..0j41.Aidial7KQqY%3D

Comment: But if you try the other expressions, you get plenty of results: https://www.google.de/search?ei=_qcPW_yyIoO7swG72ZrIBQ&q=%22Wie+war+ihr+Name+noch+gleich%22&oq=%22Wie+war+ihr+Name+noch+gleich%22&gs_l=mobile-gws-wiz-serp.12..0i8i30.9475.27880..28767...3....173.2382.22j4......0....1.........0j30i10j0i13j0i8i7i30j0i7i30.kBCtBHCx5nc%3D

Comment: @Philipp: Hmmm... could be a "neerlandism" (don't know the correct term) that slipped into the language we use around here. In Dutch we do say "Hoe was uw naam ook (al) weer?". So this may be a *very* local phenomenon. <g>

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The informal (albeit not unpolite) way to ask is, for instance:

> *Entschuldigung, wie heißt du nochmal?*

when you don't remember somebody's name. So *nochmal* is the word you look for.  I'd said it is (up to the subjunctive) the closest translation. (With the subjunctive, it is addressed in Walter's answer)

The format is thus:

> `original body of the question` + *nochmal* ?

Moreover, apparently there is  the  (not everywhere heard) [*doch (gleich)*](https://books.google.de/books?id=MiXnAAAAMAAJ&q=%22doch%20gleich%22&dq=%22doch%20gleich%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjHjpKor63bAhVKJ5oKHSSVDTsQ6AEIWDAI), instead of *nochmal*.

Comment: And it is always possible to prepend "Entschuldige" (or "Entschuldigen Sie") to make it more polite without complicating the grammar.

Comment: However, *nochmal* is not always a carrier of politeness. See *Verflixt nochmal!* where it is an amplifier for a curse.

Comment: Instead of „nochmal“ it is also common to use „noch gleich“.

Comment: More common than „noch gleich“ is actually „doch gleich“. (https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=doch+gleich%2Cnoch+gleich&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdoch%20gleich%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnoch%20gleich%3B%2Cc0 and Duden agree with me here)

Comment: I am German and I don't remember hearing "doch gleich" ever, but "noch gleich" happened occasionally. Maybe the former is an old version. "noch mal" however is the most common one in my experience and I use it, too. I also use "schon wieder".

Comment: @idmean „noch gleich“ is definitely more common around Braunschweig and Hannover.

Comment: @Alex There is probably a regional difference here. Here in Austria you'll hardly hear "noch gleich" and I personally would never say that.

Answer (score 5):

There are various forms:

> Wären Sie so freundlich, mir Ihren Namen nochmals zu sagen?

This is a polite way to ask again. In general, you could add a statement that you did not understood the name (if mentioned first time).

> Könnten Sie den Namen des Filmes nochmal wiederholen?

This is a more informal way to ask for.

Comment: "mit Ihren Namen"? I think you meant *mir*.

Comment: "nochmal wiederholen" is the equivalent of "repeat again", i.e. you want to hear it for a third time.

Answer (score 5):

In my opinion, the most polite option is to tell the reason why the other person should say something again:

> Entschuldigung, wie hieß der Film, von dem Du/Sie mir erzählt hast/haben, **nochmal**? Ich habe den Namen vergessen.
>
> Es tut mir leid, **wie war** Dein/Ihr Name? Ich habe ihn leider vergessen / Er fällt mir gerade nicht mehr ein.
>
> Das ist mir jetzt etwas unangenehm, aber ich habe Deinen/Ihren Namen vergessen. Wie hießt/hießen Du/Sie **nochmal**?
>
> Es tut mir wirklich leid, aber ich habe Deinen/Ihren Namen vergessen. Kannst/Können Du/Sie ihn mir **noch einmal** sagen?
>
> Entschuldigung, im Moment geht es mir wie dem Schriftsteller Curt Goetz. Dieser sagte einst : [‚Drei Dinge kann ich mir nicht merken: Das erste sind Namen, das zweite Zahlen, und das dritte habe ich vergessen.‘](https://www.aphorismen.de/zitat/68025) Darf ich Dich/Sie noch einmal nach Deinem/Ihrem Namen fragen?

In a more casual environment this is also very common:

> Entschuldigung, wie hieß **noch gleich** der Film, den du meintest?
>
> Du sorry, wie war dein Name **noch**? Ich hab's nicht so mit Namen.
>
> Namen sind echt nicht meins. Wie hießt du **nochmal**?

Answer (score 4):

There's also a polite way to ask again without »nochmal[s]«:

> Und dieser Film, sagten Sie, heißt bitte wie?
>
> Und dieser Film heißt bitte *wie*, sagten Sie?

Comment: I only encountered this kind of formulation in literature or older movies. But this may differ in other age groups and/or locations.

Comment: @Rhayene: Think also of phone calls.

Comment: Wow, that sounds super formal. I don't remember the last time I heard the simple past of "sagen". Makes it sound noble and theatrical.

Comment: @Alex This is because one usually tends to use the „Perfekt“ in spoken German although the „Präteritum“ would be correct in written German.

Comment: Yes, I know that. :-)